# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object even after declaring global function

Tags: php, pdo, connection

i have 12 function in my file and i get error  showing `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

and this is were problem rise

```
    <?php

function getUsers() {//returns an array of users
    global $db;
    $list = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM user_info');
    $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (is_array($users) || is_object($users))
{
    foreach ($users as $user)    {
        array_push($list, $user[0]);
    }return $list;
}
}


    $users = getUsers();
function getImageURL($user) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT propic FROM user_info WHERE username=:username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $user));
    $source = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $source;
}
```

and here is my connection file code

```
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','sanoj');
define('DBPASS','123456');
define('DBNAME','1video');

//application address
define('DIR','http://www.blogtom.com/');
define('SITEEMAIL','sanoj@gmail.com');

try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
$user = new User($db);
```

as i mentioned i have 12 function in my file can some one help me how to solve this

Comment: just make sure `$db` is a PDO instance, might be better to just inject the db instance in the functions arguments instead

Comment: you already have injected `$user = new User($db);` in your constructor? maybe you ought to use `$this->db` or some sort of property in `User` to be used inside `->getUser()` method, instead of using `global $db`. we can only guess whats inside class `User` anyways

Comment: @Ghost so what is the solution

Comment: The error message should contain a file name and lne number. Does that point to the code you've posted? How does `function getUsers()` relate to other code you've posted?

Comment: @VolkerK yes `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PDO friends 2\userData.php on line 6`

Comment: ok, that answers question #1. Question #2?

Comment: @VolkerK i don't know what's wrong can you please point out what's wrong in it

Comment: No, not with the information given so far.

Comment: @VolkerK what information are missing..?

Comment: How does `function getUsers()` relate to the other code you've posted?

Comment: the other code posted there is database connection file above code are part of file i have include connection file in header at top of file

Comment: The error message says `prepare` is on line 6. In the code you've posted it's on line 4; can you please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35544388/4833) and add the missing first two lines?

Comment: @VolkerK those missing two line are `<?php and a blank empty line` for your clarification added those lines

Comment: Ok, now when and where is the connection code included (prior to calling getUsers())? Or is it the other way round: the connection code file includes the file containing `function getUsers()`?

Comment: @VolkerK no connection file in included in `head.php` all html header etc and these function file will be loaded in `body.php`

Comment: Seems obvious that the connection code isn't executed prior to getUsers() being invoked. So please double/tripple/quadruple check and explain why you're confident that the connection code is (successfully) executed in this php instance (roughly translated: for the same http request) prior to any call to `function getUsers()`.

Comment: Your function `getImageUrl()` also uses `$db` but does not get it via `global`. You need `global $db` there as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally solved

```
function getUsers() {//returns an array of users
    global $db;
    $list = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM user_info');
    $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (is_array($users) || is_object($users)) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            array_push($list, $user[0]);
        }return $list;
    }
}

$users = getUsers();

function getImageURL($user) {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT propic FROM user_info WHERE username=:username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $user));
    $source = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $source;
}
```